# Create a dynamic project template in VS 2010?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-2008, visual-studio-2010

This might sound a bit of an odd question but I know what I want to achieve, just don't know if it's possible.

Firstly, I'd like to be able to create a visual studio project that the 2 developers that work with me can use as a basis for all new websites. I want to drop all the common files that we use in there, like jQuery, CMS files etc. so that every time they start a new project they don't have to worry about all of that stuff. I guess to do this I just set up a project and "File > Export Template" ?

Now, here's the tricky bit...

When you open up one of the default templates in VS it asks you a few questions, such as if you want to use a master page or if you want to use code behind etc.

What I would like to do is set up something similar so that when you use the project template it asks you what version of jQuery you want to use so that it can import the right file, or for example it might ask you if you want to include certain user controls that the CMS contains. If you tick the box then the folder with the necessary user controls would be put in your new project for you.

I know MS can do this but can a user like me include functionality like that in my own project template?

Hope that makes sense.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Some more digging turned up the iWizard interface and this tutorial...

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms185301